# Thread-safe file updates

Tags: c++, c, file, fopen, fwrite

I need to learn how to update a file concurrently without blocking other threads. Let me explain how it should work, needs, and how I think it should be implemented, then I ask my questions:

**Here is how the worker works:**

- Worker is multithreaded.
- There is one very large file (6 Terabyte).
- Each thread is updating part of this file.
- Each write is equal to one or more disk blocks (4096 bytes).
- No two worker write at same block (or same group of blocks) at the same time.

**Needs:**

- Threads should not block other blocks (no lock on file, or minimum possible number of locks should be used)
- In case of (any kind of) failure, There is no problem if updating block corrupts.
- In case of (any kind of) failure, blocks that are not updating should not corrupts.
- If file write was successful, we must be sure that it is not buffered and be sure that actually written on disk (fsync)
- I can convert this large file to as many smaller files as needed (down to 4kb files), but I prefer not to do that. Handling that many files is difficult, and needs a lot of file handles open/close operations, which has negative impact on performance.

**How I think it should be implemented:**

I'm not much familiar with file manipulation and how it works at operating system level, but I think writing on a single block should not corrupt other blocks when errors happen. So I think this code should perfectly work as needed, without any change:

```
char write_value[] = "...4096 bytes of data...";
int  write_block   = 12345;

int block_size = 4096;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.txt","w+");

fseek(fp, write_block * block_size, SEEK_SET);
fputs(write_value, fp);
fsync(fp);
fclose(fp);
```

**Questions:**

Obviously, I'm trying to understand how it should be implemented. So any suggestions are welcome. Specially:

1. If writing to one block of a large file fails, what is the chance of corrupting other blocks of data?
2. In short, What things should be considered on perfecting code above, (according to the last question)?
3. Is it possible to replace one block of data with another file/block atomically? (like how rename() system call replaces one file with another atomically, but in block-level. Something like replacing next-block-address of previous block in file system or whatever else).
4. Any device/file system/operating system specific notes? (This code will run on CentOS/FreeBSD (not decided yet), but I can change the OS if there is better alternative for this problem. File is on one 8TB SSD).

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Maybe you should use memory mapped files instead.

Comment: Have you tried using `open` (vs. `fopen`) and then doing `mmap`?

Comment: File updates are thread safe, guaranteed by the OS. *No two worker write at same block* - no any specific actions in your app are required.

Comment: What kind of failure do you want to protect against? Your application crashing in the middle of a write? Or some sort of operating system failure like running out of space?

Comment: Doing `fsync` after every block write can [severely] degrade performance [and `fdatasync` would probably be better].

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel unfortunately it is not possible because whole program is written in an higher level programming language (which itself is written in c/c++) and do not offer mmap functionality.

Comment: @CraigEstey As I told in reply to EtiennedeMartel using mmap is not an option.

Comment: @273K +1. That's great, so no lock, no anything else, and the code in above perfectly works, right?

Comment: @Homer512 Application crash, OS failure, electricity outage during operations, this kine of failures. The file size is fixed and will not grow.

Comment: @CraigEstey +1 for fdatasync

Comment: @CraigEstey I can periodically sync data too, for example x seconds. Is it possible to sync all finished writes at once, or it should be called on each file pointer? Google offered no answer.

Comment: *That's great, so no lock, no anything else, and the code in above perfectly works, right?* It depends on details in the implementation. If you use several file streams, one thread has written a block into its file stream, a bit later, another thread attempts to read the same file block from another file stream, it can get non actual/old data. `mmap` solves this case.

Comment: @273K Yes, each worker thread has it's own fp. Can I use fflush+fdatasync instead of mmap as others said, or is there some kind of drawbacks? (except performance differences of mmap vs fopen). I don't really care if another thread tries to read same block too soon before the block is permanently written on disk (I can handle that in the application but +1 for mentioning this possible issue), but I want to 1: make sure that data is really written on disk and is not just buffered somewhere, 2: no other block except the ones that are updating gets corrupted in case of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Threads should not block other blocks (no lock on file, or minimum possible number of locks should be used)

Your code sample uses `fseek` followed by `fwrite`. Without locking in-between those two, you have a race condition because another thread could jump in-between. There are three reasonable solutions:

1. Use `flockfile`, followed by regular `fseek` and `fwrite_unlocked` then `funlock`. Those are POSIX-2001 standard
2. Use separate file handles per thread
3. Use `pread` and `pwrite` to do IO without having to worry about the seek position

Option 3 is the best for you.

You could also use the asynchronous IO from `<aio.h>` to handle the multithreading. It basically works with a thread-pool calling `pwrite` on most Unix implementations.

> In case of (any kind of) failure, There is no problem if updating block corrupts

I understand this to mean that there should be no file corruption in any failure state. To the best of my knowledge, that is not possible when you overwrite data. When the system fails in the middle of a write command, there is no way to guarantee how many bytes were written, at least not in a file-system agnostic version.

What you can do instead is similar to a database transaction: You write the new content to a new location in the file. Then you do an fsync to ensure it is on disk. Then you overwrite a header to point to the new location. If you crash before the header is written, your crash recovery will see the old content. If the header gets written, you see the new content. However, I'm not an expert in this field. That final header update is a bit of a hand-wave.

> In case of (any kind of) failure, blocks that are not updating should not corrupts.

Should be fine

> If file write was successful, we must be sure that it is not buffered and be sure that actually written on disk (fsync)

Your sample code called `fsync`, but forgot `fflush` before that. Or you set the file buffer to unbuffered using `setvbuf`

> I can convert this large file to as many smaller files as needed (down to 4kb files), but I prefer not to do that. Handling that many files is difficult, and needs a lot of file handles open/close operations, which has negative impact on performance.

Many calls to `fsync` will kill your performance anyway. Short of reimplementing database transactions, this seems to be your best bet to achieve maximum crash recovery. The pattern is well documented and understood:

1. Create a new temporary file on the same file system as the data you want to overwrite
2. Read-Copy-Update the old content to the new temporary file
3. Call fsync
4. Rename the new file to the old file

The renaming on a single file system is atomic. Therefore this procedure will ensure after a crash, you either get the old data or the new one.

Comment: *Use `pread` and `pwrite` to do IO without having to worry about the seek position*  I'll concur that this is **THE** answer - unless you're running on Linux and appending to the file atomically is also necessary - [`pwrite()` is broken on Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html#BUGS).

Comment: @AndrewHenle The append behavior disregarding offset _is_ what one wants (i.e. _not_ broken)--otherwise just don't use `O_APPEND` (which OP isn't using anyway because s/he is doing random seeks).

Comment: @CraigEstey [No, it is not](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pwrite.html): "The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that it **writes into a given position and does not change the file offset (regardless of whether `O_APPEND` is set)**."  That allows a single file descriptor to be used to either atomically append to a file **or** atomically write to a file at a specified location.  The broken behavior of Linux here means that `pwrite()` to a file with `O_APPEND` set is no different from `write()` - the POSIX mandate is ignored.

Comment: I was going to implement it similar to database transaction-like mechanism that you mentioned. Also write+fsync+rename for keeping list of valid blocks in some other files, but I need to research more for a better alternative. The reason I don't want to split this file to many smaller files is because there will be ~1.6 billions of 4kb files, and that's just too much to handle/backup. +1 for fflush/setvbuf and other points.

Comment: Just one question, is there any advantage using mmap over fwrite+fflush+fsync? (except better performance, of course). Someone in comments mentioned that I should go with mmap. I think s/he was referring to possible issue of reading old data from another thread before fsync permanently writes data to disk and s/he was saying that using mmap solves this issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @solreus mmap + msync should work just as well. Regarding crash recovery: Have you considered using a change log that you can replay after crashes?

Comment: Yes, I want to implement change log with (almost) the same algorithm for maximum fault-tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

> If writing to one block of a large file fails, what is the chance of corrupting other blocks of data?

None.

> Is it possible to replace one block of data with another file/block atomically? (like how rename() system call replaces one file with another atomically, but in block-level. Something like replacing next-block-address of previous block in file system or whatever else).

No.

Comment: This answer could have been a comment, to be honest.

Comment: So the code in above works as intended and in any case of failure (applicaton crash, OS failure, power outage, etc) no blocks will be corrupted (except the blocks that is updating), right?

Comment: @solreus: An application crash should not corrupt non-updating blocks.  What happens during an OS failure or power outage is a much deeper question which cannot be answered here, especially not as a footnote on a broader question.  If you want to ask about that, create a new question (or look for an existing one),  and be sure to specify all the platform & filesystem specs.

Comment: I will search more on this topic and open a new question if I couldn't find an answer.  Thank you.